# Adding a Framework to multiple target in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to add existing framework to 2nd target in my project.

I added it via Build Phases-> Link Binary With Libraries -> Add Target.

But when I try to import .h file from framework or make it superclass of 2nd target, .h file is not found.

1st target has no problem, but only 2nd target has.

I searched for 3 hours but cannot find solution.

Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 0):

I assume Xcode 4? The framework should be listed on the left side in the project's hierarchy tree somewhere. If you select it, then over on the right side under Target Membership, select the second target you want it to be included in.

Comment: I did it but still it doesn't work. + I missed one information about my case. The framework i want to add is custom made .a file.